# Recreate UITabBar to UIToolbar on select from Photos app

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitoolbar

I need to do exactly what the photos app is doing when you press the *select* button. Basically just hides the `UITabBar` and presents a `UIToolbar`. For some reason this seems to be incredibly difficult if you don't want to implement a complete hack. I found a hack if you shrink the height of the `UITabBar` and change it's `alpha` to `0` but when you set it's height back to the default the image and text is condensed.

[image: Photos App]

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that I ended up just needing to call `[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES]` to hide the *tabBar* and instead of using my existing `UINavigationController`'s *toolbar* I create my own instance of a `UIToolbar` and add it as a subview of my *view controller*. Then using autolayout I pinned it to the leading, trailing, and bottom edge of the view. This handles rotation and other issues.